# Reminder Mails every week

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, reminder

I have a small workflow requirement where in i need to send reminder mails every week till the status of that item is pending. As soon as the item is completed, it should send one single mail to user and then stop sending mails.

i have created flags also to stop sending duplicate mails too.

I have already designed a workflow where in the reminder mails go after a day as i have put the condition for a day only as testing purpose, ut when i change the status to completed the mails do not go and the workflow is still in Pending stage.

Below is the image for my workflow.

[image]
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the workflow actions below, and add additional actions for your requirement:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i have created another workflow which works fine. I am attaching a screenshot below of the workflow.

[image]